# Implode 2 separate arrays?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, implode

I have a script with a query that gathers information from a db from two separate tables using a join. Now I want to insert those 2 arrays and their values side by side inside a new table.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `new_table` 
            (column_a, column_b) 
          VALUES 
            (implode(something,$array_a), implode(something,$array_b))"
```

Obviously the syntax isn't right, but I was wondering if it was possible or if I'm on the wrong track. I tried a few queries and couldn't get them to line up for an insert - it exploded them one at a time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use SELECT INTO? Something like SELECT t1.field1, t2.field2 INTO new_table FROM <join-statement>. However, if you're not restructuring/archiving, a VIEW would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this one is, as you would expect, dependent on exactly what you are trying to achieve.

I will assume that your two arrays are as follows (for the purposes of demonstration):

```
$arrayA = array(
  'Alpha' ,
  'Bravo' ,
  'Charlie'
);
$arrayB = array(
  'Zulu' ,
  'Yankee' ,
  'Xray'
);
```

Now, if you are wanting to place these values into a table (called **the_table** for ease of reference), so that they create a single row like so

```
column_a              | column_b
"Alpha,Bravo,Charlie" | "Zulu,Yankee,Xray"
```

Then the SQL you would want to produce is

```
INSERT INTO `the_table` ( `column_a` , `column_b` )
VALUES ( "Alpha,Bravo,Charlie" , "Zulu,Yankee,Xray" )
```

And the PHP to produce that SQL could be

```
$sqlTpl = 'INSERT INTO `the_table` ( `column_a` , `column_b` )
           VALUES ( "%s" , "%s" )';
$sqlStr = sprintf( $sqlTpl ,
            implode( ',' , $arrayA ) ,
            implode( ',' , $arrayB ) );
```

Now, if you were, instead, wanting to produce a set of matching rows, with one pair from each of the two arrays, like so

```
column_a  | column_b
"Alpha"   | "Zulu"
"Bravo"   | "Yankee"
"Charlie" | "Xray"
```

The SQL would be

```
INSERT INTO `the_table` ( `column_a` , `column_b` )
VALUES ( "Alpha" , "Zulu" ) ,
       ( "Bravo" , "Yankee" ) ,
       ( "Charlie" , "Xray" )
```

And the PHP to produce that could be

```
$sqlTpl = 'INSERT INTO `the_table` ( `column_a` , `column_b` )
           VALUES ( %s )';
$sqlArr = array();
foreach( $arrayA as $k => $v )
  $sqlArr[] = '"'.$arrayA[$k].'" , "'.$arrayB[$k].'"';
$sqlStr = sprintf( $sqlTpl ,
            implode( ' ) , ( ' , $sqlArr ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `new_table` 
                    (column_a, column_b) 
                  VALUES 
                    ('%s', '%s')",
                  implode(something, $array_a),
                  implode(something, $array_b));
```

That said, typically not a great idea to be storing denormalized data.

Comment: I agree with OMG Ponies, in face i would say those items belong in a table of there own, so they are related